# ArangoDB filter/collection is faster than search/view on NOT LIKE condition

Tags: node.js, database, performance, arangodb, arangojs

I created an **ArangoSearch View** on a *titles* collection. As expected most results are faster with **SEARCH** but I have this difference on a **NOT LIKE** condition:

```
FOR t in titles
    FILTER t.imdb_id != 'tt9811300'
RETURN t
```

**5.636 ms**

```
FOR t in titles_view
    SEARCH t.imdb_id != 'tt9811300'
RETURN t
```

**17.767 ms**

The *titles_view* configuration:

```
{
  "writebufferIdle": 64,
  "type": "arangosearch",
  "writebufferSizeMax": 33554432,
  "consolidationPolicy": {
    "type": "tier",
    "segmentsBytesFloor": 2097152,
    "segmentsBytesMax": 5368709120,
    "segmentsMax": 10,
    "segmentsMin": 1,
    "minScore": 0
  },
  "primarySort": [],
  "globallyUniqueId": "h89046D31F32C/10434587",
  "id": "10434587",
  "storedValues": [],
  "writebufferActive": 0,
  "consolidationIntervalMsec": 1000,
  "cleanupIntervalStep": 2,
  "commitIntervalMsec": 1000,
  "links": {
    "titles": {
      "analyzers": [
        "identity"
      ],
      "fields": {},
      "includeAllFields": true,
      "storeValues": "none",
      "trackListPositions": false
    }
  },
  "primarySortCompression": "lz4"
}
```